# Django returning HTTP 301?

Tags: django, curl, libcurl

I have a django view that returns HTTP 301 on a curl request:

```
grapefruit:~ pete$ curl -I http://someurl
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2009 19:01:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) mod_wsgi/2.5 Python/2.6.2 PHP/5.2.6
Location: http://someurl
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I can't get the page's content from curl. However, if I visit the page with a browser, I see the content as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You are probably requesting the URL without a trailing slash, and have `APPEND_SLASH` set to True (the default) in settings.py, so Django is redirecting to the URL including a slash.

Comment: The funny thing is that from Postman there is no such problem(301). I guess Postman adds the slash.

Comment: What happened for me is that I needed to add an `Authorization` header on my requests. On safari, it would 301 and send back as unauthorized because it wouldn't carry over the header when the redirect happened. I was used to Chrome and Safari doing this automatically. Adding the slash worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

So for me, it was a combination of the following:

- `SecurityMiddleware` enabled
- `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True`
- Separate Web Server had SSL redirect enabled as well

In that case, the web server already does the redirecting and forwards the request via HTTP to Django, which then redirects again to HTTPS which ends in an infinite loop.

So, in that case, it's safe to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False`.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was PREPEND_WWW, when using it in localhost it returns a 301 error, I just created a local settings file and set it PREPEND_WWW = False

Answer (score 3):

In my case, commenting the **SecurityMiddleware** on the `settings.py` file did the trick. I have to say that this only happens when running the `runserver` command (aka. when testing). With Apache it doesn't falls into the redirect loop.

Comment: In my case, it happened on prod with gunicorn. The server returns the exact same Location as passed wich turns into an endless loop. I worked-around that issue by only setting `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` instead of completely removing the SecurityMiddleware. But I am wondering why that happens and how to actually fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When using postman everything was working okay but when i was requesting it from the frontend i was getting the 301 error. You are probably missing the trailing slash in the url, i had the same problem and i solved it by adding the slash to the url....

Comment: Maybe Postman is following the redirection

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please check URL you may be missing **slash** some where.
I fixed this by adding slash at the end of URL

Comment: Please do not repeat other's answers. This is a duplicate of [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579859/14401160), which is more detailed and is >10 years old. If you want to support an existing answer, please upvote it.