# How to pass variables with google protocol buffers when using django? bitcoin bips in particular

Tags: python, django, protocol-buffers, bitcoin

Link to protofile [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070/paymentrequest.proto).

I need to pass a hash , a database ref, anything really so that I can know for sure that a customer visiting my payment request url came from my website and isn't some arbitrary bot pinging me and causing me to create new btc addresses for no reason.

I tried the following:

```
bitcoin:<non-bip-btcaddress>?r=http://127.0.0.1:8000/paymentobject/?ref=<unique-hash>
```

but it wasn't compatible with mobile wallets.

I'm now trying to pass a param inside urls.py

```
#urls.py
url(r'^paymentobject/(?P<ref>\w+)/$', 'project.views.paymentobject', name='paymentobject'),

#views.py
def paymentobject(request, ref):
    secret = ref #and so on...
```

This approach works in the browser and I'm able to download the octet-stream file just fine, however when accessing the uri through bitcoin-qt (0.9x) or a mobile wallet I'm met with the error:

```
301: MOVED PERMANENTLY
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the trailing slash was missing from the end of the url below.

```
btcbip_url = 'bitcoin:%s?r=%s/paymentobject/%s/'
```

Original anser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579846/django-returning-http-301).