# 301 when requesting REST without HTTPS

Tags: django, https, django-rest-framework

I have an API working just fine on one URL (it returns a nice 201 CREATED):

```
curl -d @scan.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin -i -v "https://vincentle.pythonanywhere.com/api/beacons/"
```

But when I try to perform the same request without the SSL:

```
curl -d @scan.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin -i -v "http://vincentle.pythonanywhere.com/api/beacons/"
```

I get a `301 Moved Permanently` response.

I have tried two fixes:

1. I defined a URL without the trailing slash ([after reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579846/django-returning-http-301)). This is not the solution, request with, or without slash will return 301.
2. I added a header "`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO: https`" in my request, as I have the line `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` in my settings. This isn't the solution either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at where you are redirected to.
My bet, your configuration does redirect http to https in which case it's an administration issue unrelating to Django / Django REST framework.

Comment: I'm redirected to the https url. Maybe data is lost during redirect?

Comment: Yup, usually the redirection is a GET. I think you could force curl to resend the data by explicitly set -XPOST on top of your current arguments.

Comment: I've added a SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = [r'.*/api/beacons/', ] in my settings, but my http is still redirecting to https, do you know why?

Comment: This may be linked to your front server configuration. Django isn't the only one here.