# post menthod not working when send data from reactjs to django restful api

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, django-rest-framework

here is my post method code in react

```
const URL = `http://localhost:8000`
export default URL;

export function addRecruiterRegister(values,cb){
    const request=fetch(`${URL}/recruiterRegister`,{
        method:'POST',
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
        }).then(
          //  () => cb()
        )

        return {
            type:'ADD_RECRUITER',
            payload:'everything went fine'
    }
}
```

here is the code in django-python

```
class RecruiterRegisterList(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset=RecruiterRegister.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecruiterRegisterSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields=('email','password')

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = RecruiterRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        recruiterRegisters = self.get_object()
        recruiterRegisters.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**error in the browser console:**

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/recruiterRegister' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
:3000/#/forms/recruiter-register-form:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

**and in python console i am getting this when i click submit:**

"OPTIONS /recruiterRegister HTTP/1.1" 301 0

**very new to django-restframework and reactjs, please help!!**

Comment: Although get method is working

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem caused by [`generics.ListAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview). This is only have `get` method. If you want to make `post` request also, you should use [`generics.CreateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview).

```
class RecruiterRegisterList(generics.CreateAPIView,
                            generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset=RecruiterRegister.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecruiterRegisterSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields=('email','password')

    ...
```

Comment: no it is not working.Although i could post through postman before also.

Comment: Can you change your url `${URL}/recruiterRegister` to `${URL}/recruiterRegister/`?

Comment: lastly, have you ever check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579846/django-returning-http-301) and try to do `post` request with postman?