# Angular HttpClient infinite loading by set header bearer

Tags: django, angular, api, http, angular8

I have this code to get data from API

```
return this.httpClient.get<any>(requestUrl, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.cookieService.get('auth-token'),
      }),
    });
```

when I subscribe to this like this

```
return this.api.loadAll('cuser').subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log(result);

  },
);
```

**It doesn't return any data to me and just loading**

but when I remove the headers and call it again it shows me the data.

```
return this.httpClient.get<any>(requestUrl, {
  // headers: new HttpHeaders({
  //   "Content-Type": "application/json",
  //   "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.cookieService.get('auth-token'),
  // }),
});
```

But I need the Authorization and the token to get current user data from Django back-end.

So what make my code wrong?

Following is the Post man sample that return correct data without issue

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkyNTUxMTE3LCJqdGkiOiIxMGJlZWExMDQ0MmE0NmUyOGVmM2E5NTBjY2NiNTRmOSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.5XOhaXANSk4CGbh7pHqE99Qh_yxj6YuewZHFC1UScIs");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/cuser", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

[image]

[image]

**No any error just in the network it shows the pending status**
The back-end log during the request

[image]

Comment: Any errors? Your angular code is alright, but your backend seems to not return anything.

Comment: Looks from the screenshot the token is empty in the `Authorization` header. Check if `this.cookieService.get('auth-token')` actually returns a valid token.

Comment: @MichaelD auth-token set up correctly as I use it for the post request the same.

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi: Then please elaborate why it looks empty in the `Request Headers` section of the screenshot.

Comment: @MikeS. No error, please check the update on the question

Comment: @MichaelD I just add a log on the function that call the api, and it return the token successfully. I add this `console.log('Token is :' + this.cookieService.get('auth-token'));` just before the http request.

Comment: Your token is not included in the request, configure your backend to return `401` when the token is missing. As for why it's not included, try to get the token prior to your call and append it to the headers using `append` or `set` (Basically what you did in the last code sample)

Comment: Thanks, I figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out it, actually the issue with back-end and **HTTP 301** response. The requested API should be ended with slash.
So I added a slash at the end of the requested URL and the issue fixed.

> REF https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579859/9246297

The successful request after adding slash

[image: The successful request after adding slash]

The failed request without slash at the end of the request

[image: The failed request without slash at the end of the request]